# mysql underperforming on ec2

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

we are trying to transfer from our data center to aws. In both situations we have a few web servers with one master and two slave databases. We had to pull the switch monday back to the data center though. The ec2 mysql slaves were taking between 40 and 140 seconds to execute the homepage queries that take 1s tops from our data center. We are using 1 large and 1 xl slave, which should be actually a little more powerful than what we have in the datacenter. During that time our slave ec2s had a solid 100% cpu level. They have mounted ebs volumes. Anyone have any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Maybe at serverfault You will have better answers. I've heard that sql performs badly on aws. Try more aggressive caching maybe. Pages should load to the browser in less than 1 second and I personally try to make all queries under 0.2 seconds per page...

Comment: I've been using MySQL on AWS for 1.5 years and have not noticed a negligible difference so it must be some other setup / software issue you are dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

EBS do not guarantee throughput (until last year). You will want to try to use a provisioned IOPS mounted volume. This way your disk io is guaranteed and then you can rule out EBS as the problem.

http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/08/fast-forward-provisioned-iops-ebs.html

(that is assuming you have ensured all your indexes are on the tables and all application level stuff is the same)

Answer (score 0):

If you homepage uses SQL-subqueries than EC2 instance might be very slow as by default it uses MySQL 5.5 (for mor detail look at [MySQL is extremely slow on EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255238/mysql-is-extremely-slow-on-ec2/17255263))