# Query Speed on Mysql 5.5 (Ubuntu) vs Mysql 5.1 (Windows 7) - Drastic Difference

Tags: mysql, performance, ubuntu

I have two IDENTICAL databases:

Database 1:
Version: 5.1.68-community
OS: Windows 7 Professional (64 Bit)

Database 2:
Version: 5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
OS: Ubuntu Server 12.04 (64 Bit)

DB Size (both DBs): 25 MB

Querying DB 1:
Query - call ledger('2013-08-19','%','%','%','%','%');
Response: 72 row(s) returned
Duration: 0.452 sec / 0.000 sec

Querying DB 2:
Query - call ledger('2013-08-19','%','%','%','%','%');
Response: 72 row(s) returned
Duration: 25.959 sec / 0.000 sec

Running queries outside the procedure yields very similar results.

What could be causing such drastic difference?
0.452  vs 25.959.. Difference in performance is Huge.

Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, would you be able to run the same tests with MariaDB? https://mariadb.org/

Comment: Also, what happens when you run MySQL 5.1 on Ubuntu?

Comment: Is there a difference in hardware?

Comment: Thanks for the follow up guys. @ngneema hardware is almost identical. Windows has twice as much RAM but ubuntu is a dedicated production server that runs only Apache and mysql.

Comment: @homer6 I hound this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255238/mysql-is-extremely-slow-on-ec2

Comment: looks like sub queries are causing the issue. removed 6 sub-queries and performance is almost identical

Comment: Will try installing 5.1 on Virtual Box to compare

Comment: @user1431213 Good find. I guess it was the subquery performance of 5.5... did using 5.6 improve it (like the other post)?

Comment: @Homer6 did not have chance to test yet. Will let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code of the `ledger()` procedure?

Comment: @ypercube http://s8.postimg.org/cwuuodsg5/image.png http://s15.postimg.org/6w08e1pyz/image.png

Comment: Case is resolved! Apparently Trim Function in Where Clause was causing all the "issues". No clue why, but I removed it and performance improved by nearly 1000%. Thank you everyone for your help.